# Running jacoco from gradle on already instrumented files

Tags: java, gradle, jacoco

I am trying jacoco offline instrumentation for a java project.

I created a hello world gradle java project and instrumented its generated class files with jacoco. When I am trying to run tests on these instrumented files. I am getting following error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException at CUTest.java:-1

The decompiled test .class file is

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class CUTest
{
  public CUTest()
  {
    arrayOfBoolean[0] = true;
  }

  @Test
  public void test()
  {
    boolean[] arrayOfBoolean = $jacocoInit();CUT localCUT1 = new CUT();arrayOfBoolean[1] = true;
    CUT c;
    c.meth();
    arrayOfBoolean[2] = true;
  }
}
```

instrumented source .class file is

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class CUT
{
  public CUT()
  {
    arrayOfBoolean[0] = true;
  }

  public void meth()
  {
    boolean[] arrayOfBoolean = $jacocoInit();System.out.println("hello world");
    arrayOfBoolean[1] = true;
  }
}
```

jacoco agent jar is present on classpath. I added a test compile dependency for that in build.gradle.

Here's source file (not decompiled class file)

```
public class CUT {

    public void meth(){
        System.out.println("hello world");
    }

}
```

Test source

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class CUTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        CUT c = new CUT();
        c.meth();
    }

}
```

I used jacoco instrumentation api to instrument class file generated after compiling these classes.
I want to generate jacoco report from these .class files(already instrumented).

Here are projects for hello world and instrumentation 
https://github.com/arpitgautam/jacoco-rat
https://github.com/arpitgautam/jacoco

Comment: Source file doesn't compile. Please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thoese are jacoco instrumented decompiled .class files.Source code also added now.

Comment: This is still not enough to reproduce your problem. How **exactly** you instrument classes? How **exactly** execute? How **exactly** create report?

Comment: I used jacoco api in a separate java project to instrument the class files.  I will upload both projects on github and share path here tomorrow. Is the method I am using correct. Is there a way to run jacoco on already instrumented class files sitting on disk?
I am using gradle to compile java classes. Then take generated class files and instrument them externally to place them back.
Then I use gradle to run test cases again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example from https://github.com/arpitgautam/jacoco-rat at commit `f4786df19a930726ebada97461d2a54ad463a4ec` as described in `README.md`:

> ```
> gradle build
> ```
>
> Uncomment gradle.taskGraph.beforeTask from build.gradle

but during

> Take files in jacoco-rat\build\classes and instrument those using jacoco instrumentation api replace classes by the instrumented ones.

using your https://github.com/arpitgautam/jacoco at commit `5e7ac40627eb4e2f0882ce143f5840ee9774af57` that requires

> change ROOT to absolute path of classes folder

which is in my case

```
public static final String ROOT = "/tmp/jacoco-rat/build/classes/";
```

got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 32
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
    at com.exp.tools.JavaClassVisitor.createNewFolderName(JavaClassVisitor.java:69)
```

so instead used [JaCoCo command-line interface](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html) (that will be available in next version) to instrument classes:

```
java -jar jacococli.jar instrument build/classes --dest build/instrumented
```

and replaced originals:

```
rm -r build/classes
mv build/instrumented build/classes
```

Then executed Gradle again as `gradle test --info` and see that exception is not `java.lang.ClassCastException`, but

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_8ff85ea/Offline
    at com.exp.tools.CUTest.$jacocoInit(CUTest.java)
    at com.exp.tools.CUTest.<init>(CUTest.java)

    Caused by:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_8ff85ea.Offline
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 2 more
```

quoting [JaCoCo FAQ](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html):

> Why do I get an error "ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.agent[...]Offline"?
>
> If you use offline instrumentation the instrumented classes get a direct dependency on the JaCoCo runtime. Therefore jacocoagent.jar of the same JaCoCo version must be on the classpath and accessible from by the instrumented classes.

according to http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/repo.html :

> ```
> Group ID    Artifact ID       Description
> org.jacoco  org.jacoco.agent  API to get a local copy of the agent
> ```

artifact `org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent` in Maven repository is not an actual agent, but an API to get it. Actual agent has classifier `runtime`, i.e instead of

```
testCompile group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', version: '0.7.9'
```

you definitely should use

```
testCompile group: 'org.jacoco', name: 'org.jacoco.agent', classifier: 'runtime', version: '0.7.9'
```

and fix problems in https://github.com/arpitgautam/jacoco where among others you maybe wrongly use JaCoCo APIs causing `java.lang.ClassCastException`, or use already developed standard JaCoCo tools to do instrumentation such as already mentioned above upcoming Command Line Interface, [Ant Tasks](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html), [Maven Plugin](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/instrument-mojo.html), [etc](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/integrations.html).

Comment: I will wait for jacococli.jar to release. Its not on maven. Is it available via some other channel?

Comment: @Arpit you can build from sources, or download from snapshot maven repository - see download link at main page http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/ and link to snapshot repository in documentation http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/repo.html  Also you already can use Ant Task "instrument" to do the same - http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html Please don't forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted.